Problem using VTL code in AWS CLI's response-templates
I'm trying to specify Velocity Template Language (VTL) code using the --response-templates option while creating a resource in API Gateway with AWS CLI. However, when I run the command, I'm getting unexpected errors and it seems like the VTL code is not being processed correctly.
I want to use a Lambda function in API Gateway to achieve customized CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) behavior. This Lambda function will process incoming requests and add appropriate CORS headers, using Velocity Template Language (VTL) code.
First, I create a resource and path in API Gateway, and then I integrate this resource with a Lambda function. Then, I attempt to customize the Lambda function's response using the --response-templates option. However, when I run the command, I encounter errors related to the VTL code inside the JSON string.
I'm using the following command:
aws apigateway put-integration-response --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> --resource-id <resource-id> --http-method GET --status-code 200 --response-templates '{"application/json":"\"#set($context.responseOverride.header[\\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\\"] = $input.params(''origin'')\")"}' 
Can you help me please?

You can use this to set that header:
aws apigateway put-integration-response --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> --resource-id <resource-id> --http-method GET --status-code 200 --response-templates '{"application/json": "#set($context.responseOverride.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin=$input.params(\"origin\"))"}'

And this and enhanced version of CORS configuration
aws apigateway put-integration-response --rest-api-id <api-id> --resource-id <resource-id> --http-method OPTIONS --status-code 200 --response-templates '{"application/json": "#set($domains = [\"https://test.com\", \"http://localhost:3000\", \"http://localhost:3001\"])\n#set($origin = $input.params(\"origin\"))\n#if($domains.contains($origin))\n#set($context.responseOverride.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin=$origin)\n#end"}

